# How to include autocomplete street-address with address-line1 and address-line2 in form (semantics)

Tags: html, autocomplete

I'm writing a simple form that asks the user for their home address. I have line1, line2, city, state, zip. My confusion comes from [this description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values) at MDN:

> "address-line1", "address-line2", "address-line3"
>      Each individual line of the street address. **These should only be present if the "street-address" is also present.**

My question is: how am I supposed to include both "street-address" and "address-line1" autocomplete tags?

```
<div>
  <label for="addr1">Address Line 1</label>
  <input name="addr1" id="addr1" autocomplete="address-line1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="addr2">Address Line 2</label>
  <input name="addr2" id="addr2" autocomplete="address-line2">
</div>
```

But that doesn't have "street-address", so goes against the MDN guide.

Answer (score 0):

> Each individual line of the street address. These should only be
> present if the "street-address" is **not** present.

Comment: Looks like they changed that text sometime around/before Sep 2020, which is as far back as the history goes on the current github hosting. Makes more sense now.